# Method sp_OAGetProperty does not return value when executed

Tags: t-sql, ole, google-geocoder

I have a certain address for a client and I need to get the latitude and longitude coordinates from Google using API Key, however either sp_OAGetProperty is returning blank instead of an XML data, what could be the reason for blank results it is returning?

This is for a geo analytics purposes, I have reconfigured the server to accept the execution of Ole Automation Procedures but still the same.

I'm using code.

```
use Development_Weekly
go

DECLARE @Response varchar(8000)
DECLARE @XML xml
DECLARE @Obj int 
DECLARE @Result int 
DECLARE @HTTPStatus int 
DECLARE @Erreur varchar(MAX)
declare @MessageErreur varchar(max)
declare @MessageErreurAvecNumero varchar(max)

declare  @URL varchar(600) =(select top 1 [BranchAddressURL] from [Development_Weekly].[dbo].[vwBranchLocation])
EXEC @Result = sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp', @Obj OUT 
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OACreate MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'   end
--BEGIN TRY
EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'open', NULL, 'GET', @URL, false
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'   end

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, 'setRequestHeader', NULL, 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'   end

EXEC @Result = sp_OAMethod @Obj, send, NULL, ''
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAMethod MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'  end

EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml', @Response OUT 
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OAGetProperty MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'   end

EXEC @Result = sp_OADestroy @Obj
if @Erreur <> 0 begin set @MessageErreur = 'sp_OADestroy MSXML2.ServerXMLHttp.3.0 failed'   end

select @Result,@Response,@URL
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the reason is without a real url. But I always insert the response to a table variable instead of using `@Response OUT` to avoid truncated result. Here is what I usually do:

```
DECLARE @TABLEVAR TABLE (responseXml VARCHAR(MAX))

--skip some codes here

INSERT INTO @TABLEVAR
EXEC @Result = sp_OAGetProperty @Obj, 'responseXML.xml' --, @Response OUT 
EXEC sp_OADestroy @Obj

SELECT @Response = responseXml FROM @TABLEVAR
```